# Web API Help page not showing XML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have a Web API project in which I removed by hand *Areas* folder few months ago when we started development. Now after everything is finished I want to add API help pages but it is not working as expected.

I installed nuget package for help pages.

I uncommented line in `HelpPageConfig.cs`

I checked *Generate documentation file* (to App_Data folder)

When I open *http://localhost:51665/help* I get this: (No methods are shown)

[image]

Any idea what could be wrong?  If I start new project from scratch everything works properly.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you've setup your project in two steps:

1. You should choose **Build** tab in API project **Properties** and set up XML Documentation file in **Output** section. For example: `App_Data\XmlDocument.xml`
2. Then you can update`HelpPageConfig.cs` in method `Register`... in my case

`config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));`

- When your project is in compilation process, take a look in output window, whether documentation is really generated.
- Try to use older version of ASP.NET Help pages (version 5.2.2 works for me).

  `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage -Version 5.2.2`